# Move 2d circle automatically with constant speed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opengl

I want to move a 2d circle in opengl automatically with constant speed on load and then control it with keyboard to move smoothly.

Right now i have the code to move the circle with keyboard, but it is moving only one unit for every keypress.

I want a smooth movement when keypress and automatic movement when on load.

Answer (score 1):

Use glTranslatef to move your object, or alternatively you can just adjust its position x,y,z by a set amount in each update cycle when the keyboard keys are pressed.

E.g

```
const float MOVE_AMOUNT = 5.0;

public void Update()
{
     if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown("a"))
         circle.position.x -= MOVE_AMOUNT;

     else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown("d"))
         circle.position.y += MOVE_AMOUNT;
}
```

NOTE: this is not valid C++ syntax, but it gives the overall logic of what you need to be doing, you should be able to figure it out from this. If you want a glTranslate example please let me know.

Comment: I'd also pass the time in seconds that has passed since the last frame and multiply it with the move amount to have a framerate independent movement: `public void Update(const double &time)` and `circle.position.x -= MOVE_AMOUNT*time;` where time would be 0.0xx.